# prove integral converge in $[0, \infty)$

Tags: integration

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous functions in $[0, \infty)$.
I need to prove that if $\int_{0}^{\infty} f^{2}(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} g^{2}(x)\,dx$ converge then $\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(x)+g(x))^{2}\,dx~$  converge.
Can you guide me I dont know from where to start. Thanks.

Comment: Forget about the integral for a moment. Can you find $k$ so that $k(a^2+b^2)>(a+b)^2$?

Comment: Hint: note that $(f(x)+g(x))^2=f^2(x)+g^2(x)+2f(x)g(x)$

Comment: Hint: Note that $$(f(x)+g(x))^2\leqslant2(f(x)^2+g(x)^2).$$ Proof: Compute the RHS minus the LHS and marvel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
\begin{align*}
(f+g)^2 & =f^2+g^2+2fg\\
\int_0^{\infty}(f+g)^2 \, dx & \leq \int_0^{\infty}f^2 \, dx+\int_0^{\infty}g^2 \, dx+2\int_0^{\infty}|fg| \, dx.
\end{align*}
Now use Holder's inequality (or Cauchy-Schwarz) for the last term.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do you know that |fg| converge ?

Comment: @Dani please read the last sentence. To show that last term converges you need to use Holder's inequality.

Comment: Yes.Thanks!!!!!